# Guidance creating jest.config.file

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I'm using Jest in my Node app and I get the following message in the console:

*Mongoose: looks like you're trying to test a Mongoose app with Jest's default jsdom test environment. Please make sure you read Mongoose's docs on configuring Jest to test Node.js apps: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/jest.html*

I have read the documentation but it feels like they expect me to be familiar with this library when this is my first time using it. The documentation says to add this piece of code:

```
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: 'node'
};
```

To my `jest.config.js` file, but where is this file?, where in my dir am I supposed to create this file? I created the file in the root of my project folder and added the previous piece of code but the message still remains in the console. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 9):

You can configure jest directly on your `package.json` file.

```
  ...,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --exec babel-node server/index.js",
    "build": "babel server --out-dir dist",
    "serve": "node dist/index.js",
    "test": "jest --watchAll --verbose --detectOpenHandles ./server/api"
  },
  "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  },
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

for every project u need to setup configuration settings. i use env-cmd package which is very clean and does not give u any headache.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd

```
npm install env-cmd
```

then create a /config directory in your root folder. create a dev.env and test.env file inside of it. enter your variables here like this.

/config/dev.env  //nothing in the strings

```
PORT=3000
MONGODB_URL=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/rest-api
```

/config/test.env

```
PORT=3000
MONGODB_URL=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/rest-api-TESTING
```

note that for naming convention, env variables are always capital letters and we separate them by "_". and values are NOT strings. also it is important that u do not use the same db in testing environment so u wont pollute the dev db.

now you need to configure the package.json file. in "scripts" we usually have start, dev, test scripts. start is for deployment platforms, test for testing and dev for our current development environment. if you are using nodemon (most likely u are) your dev scripts should like this.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node src/index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon src/index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

when you run npm run dev, terminal will run this nodemon src/index.js. this is a basic configuration for any node app. now we need to pass our variables that stored in /config/dev.env. to our application. for this change "dev" and "test" like below:

```
"dev": "env-cmd -f ./config/dev.env nodemon src/index.js",
"test": "env-cmd ./config/test.env jest --watchAll"
```

now when u run `npm run test` express will load all the configurations settings in the config/test.env. we need to add one more setting to package.json:

```
"jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  },
```

this is how u use configuration setting. for connecting mongodb

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false
})
```

if you call `npm run dev`, express will load the settings from ./config/dev.env, if u call `npm run test` express will load the settings from ./config/test.env

NOTE that when you deploy your project to github, you have add config folder name to .gitignore file. so your passwords or api keys are not gonna be public.

also everytime you add a new variable to the dev.env kill terminal process and restart it. mongodb will give error.

Answer (score -1):

Well,  the instruction on https://mongoosejs.com/docs/jest.html means you need to change default config setting if your environment is node. So you can change testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom' to testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-node', which can be found in ../node_modules/jest-config/build/Defaults.js. 
Hoping I answered your question...

Comment: change the default settings to what?

Comment: As I mentioned, change testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom' to testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-node' in Default.js.  Good luck man.